# Add an current object Parameter to User

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm new to Rails and I am struggling with something that should be easy.

I'm working on a Football related app. I have many Users that can have many Clubs. I'm currently trying to implement a way to keep in memory the current Club for a User so that every action taken by the User when a certain club is set as the current Club influences said Club (similarly to the famous session "current_user").

The idea being that the User can easily switch to control one Club or another by coming back on his home page and clicking on the name of the Club he wants to control.

I have tried it alot of ways but I can't seem to be able to make it work.

Lately I've tried to add a column "current_club_id" to my User model but I'm unable to modify the value of this parameter (it stays null wathever I do)

Here is my latest trial :

In my user/show, I have <% render @clubs %> with _club:

```
<tr>
  <td class="club">
    <span class="nom"><%= button_to club.nom, {:action => "assign_active_club", :controller => "users",  :id => current_user.id, :user => User.find(current_user.id) , :active_club_id => club.id } %></span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

and in my users_controller:

```
def assign_active_club
      @club = Club.find(params[:active_club_id])
      @user.define_active_club(params[:active_club_id])
      @user.save
      flash[:success] = "The active club of the user " + @user.name.to_s + " is nom " +@club.name.to_s
      redirect_to @club
    end
```

and finally in the user.rb

```
 def define_active_club(id)
    self.current_club_id = id
  end
```

The user does not save. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the 'user' as a parameter via the button, but you're not actually setting the '@user' instance variable in the controller. What happens if you get rid of this in the view:

```
:user => User.find(current_user.id)
```

with this in the controller:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

?

Comment: Still the same, the current_club_id stays null. The real problem is that it seems that this value seems "unmodifiable". I tried to add a a line to modifiy the stadium of the club (an object belonging to the club)
 def define_active_club(id)
    self.current_club_id = id
    self.stade.size += 5000
  end

and this change was saved in the database.
Can you think of a reason why a parameter could be "unmodifiable"?

Comment: The only way I succeeded to modifiy the current_club_id is within the initialisation method of my model. But after that, again, it seems unmodifiable